# Get TypedDependencies using StanfordParser Shift Reduce Parser

Tags: stanford-nlp, shift-reduce

I am trying to use the Stanford Shift Reduce Parser with the Spanish model supplied. I am noticing, however, that unlike the Lexicalized Parser, I cannot get the TypedDependencies, despite sending the adequate flag -outputFormat typedDependencies, as it can be seen in lexparser.bat/sh.

Just in case, this is the Java code I'm using to pass the flags and creating the parser.

```
ShiftReduceParser model = ShiftReduceParser.loadModel(modelPath);
model.setOptionFlags("-factored", "-outputFormat", "penn,typedDependencies");
ArrayList<TaggedWord> taggedWords = new ArrayList<TaggedWord>();
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not the ShiftReduceParser, but simply that we don't currently support typed dependencies for Spanish currently - we only have them for English and Chinese.

(Looking ahead, the most likely thing to appear first is support for [Universal Dependencies](http://universaldependencies.github.io/docs/) in the [Neural Network Dependency Parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml). Indeed, you could probably train such a model yourself now.)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't sure whether it was the parser or the model, because there is no Spanish model for the LexicalizedParser, so I wasn't quite sure. Thank you for your response!